# How to Call a method every time when Network is Available in Android?

Tags: android, android-volley, job-queue

Scenario is When my Application is offline, i am Storing Some information in database which i need to send to server. So when Network is available i want to send those by Api calls. Is there any way to call a method every time when Network is available??

Comment: use broadcast receiver

Comment: you have to use broadcast receiver

Comment: If you're targeting android N Preview. Receiver will not work as per constrained restricted by Google. Link: https://developer.android.com/preview/features/background-optimization.html#connectivity-action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create broadcastReceiver:

```
public class InternetBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
static final String TAG = "InternetReceiver";
private static int networkType = -1;
private static boolean connectedWithNetwork = false;

public static void initNetworkStatus(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    networkType = -1;
    if (networkInfo != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Init: ACTIVE NetworkInfo: " + networkInfo.toString());
        if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            networkType = networkInfo.getType();
        }
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "initNetworkStatus -> " + networkType);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onReceive " + intent.getAction());

    try {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SHUTDOWN)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "System shutdown, stopping yaxim.");
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {


            ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            boolean isConnected = (networkInfo != null) && (networkInfo.isConnected() == true);
            boolean wasConnected = (networkType != -1);

            if (connectedWithNetwork && isConnected)
                return;

            connectedWithNetwork = isConnected;

            if (wasConnected && !isConnected) {
                Log.d(TAG, "we got disconnected");
                networkType = -1;

            } else if (isConnected && (networkInfo.getType() != networkType)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "we got (re)connected: " + networkInfo.toString());
                networkType = networkInfo.getType();
                try {
                    Intent bIntent = new Intent("custom-event-name");
                    bIntent.putExtra("subject", Utils.SUBJECT_INTERNET_CONNECTED);
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(bIntent);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (isConnected && (networkInfo.getType() == networkType)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "we stay connected, sending a ping");
                try {
                    Intent bIntent = new Intent("custom-event-name");
                    bIntent.putExtra("subject", Utils.SUBJECT_INTERNET_CONNECTED);
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(bIntent);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else
                return;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

and register in manifest file

```
<receiver android:name=".packagename.InternetBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/// BROADCAST RECEIVER CLASS

    public class UpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
    {



        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) 
    {

            boolean isConnected = arg1.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
            if (isConnected) {

            } else {

               //FETCH YOUR DATA FROM SQLITE

               //CALL API

            }
        }
    }   



/// ANDROID MANIFEST CODE

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

  <receiver android:name="com.example.welcome.nkew.UiUtils.UpdateReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Thanks all for your answers. it helped me alot